# How to set up network for Ekiga on Arch Linux?

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I've got two machines with identical Ekiga versions and settings (including accounts), both behind the same router. Both have contacts referencing myself and the standard call back test.

Machine A:

- Up to date Ubuntu 13.04
- Connected to wireless network

Machine B:

- Up to date Arch Linux
- Connected to wired network

No [port forwarding](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Enable_port_forwarding_manually) is set up on the router. On machine A, after logging in, my "self" contact shows I'm online and I'm able to successfully complete a call back test with audio and video. After logging out on machine A and logging in on machine B, I do *not* see myself as online and the call back test just opens the call window for a long time and never calls back. No messages are displayed indicating what is happening. Some debug output:

```
$ ekiga -d 4 2>&1 | grep STUN | cut -f 3-
                        Ekiga   Started STUN detector
StunDetect...6b8651d700 OPAL    STUN server "stun.ekiga.net" replies Cone NAT, external IP 91.190.8.175
Housekeepe...6b8c0dd700 Ekiga   Stopped STUN detector
                        MonSock Created bundled UDP socket via STUN, internal=192.168.1.3:5060, external=91.190.8.175:5060
```

I don't get any "[PDU is likely too large](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Troubleshooting#I_register.2C_but_the_communication_cannot_be_established)" messages.

I tried setting up port forwarding to machine B as well. The result is that machine A complains "Ekiga did not manage to configure your network settings automatically", but machine B is still not able to do anything. Despite the warning and the port forwarding setup, machine A is still able to successfully complete a call back test.

The only difference I could find in the two clients is that A has some extra video codecs - H263, H263-1998 and MP4V-ES, to be specific.